# Get or Set localStorage Value inside Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, javascript-objects

I am here playing with the local Storage. And Want it to get or set the value of local storage inside an object. I know the set or get item is the recommended operations for this but somewhere i found that :

LocalStorage can also be set by using : `localStorage.myvalue = "something";`

And for getting the current value we simply call : `localStorage.myvalue;`
Now I put this in an object like :

```
var myObj = {
  myval: localStorage.myvalue
}
```

When i set the value of `myObj.myval="somethingAgain"`;

Then this doesn't Works, Normally the objects can be easily set or get by this method,but in this case why it so happens??

The retrieval of the value is working by calling `myObj.myval` but why i am not able to set the value here??

So Suggest me where I am Wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like it could be accomplished with this following small adjustment.

**Update:**

Seemed too long for  you, shorthand better?

```
var myObj = {
    myval: function(val){ 
        return (typeof (val) === 'undefined' ? localStorage.myvalue : localStorage.myvalue=val);
    }
}
```

Than calling it like this to set

```
myObj.myval("Add this");
```

or to get

```
myObj.myval();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4WsNx/

Hope this helps.

Comment: ya, you right but ,what if i also want the return value from the same?
and please give me the proper reason behind it why my code doesn't work ?

Comment: i edited mine so you can use the same object for both requests just by omitting the value it will get, and by adding the value in the () it will set

Comment: And What about the Shorthand of @FUserThrowError User ??

Comment: Hmm not sure sorry. If FUserThrowError has answered the question for you, by all means accept his :). personally the way I did it is the way I would use it, seems cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

First

```
localStorage.a = "value";

// create object
var ob = { a: localStorage.a };

console.log(ob.a); // "value"
```

When you doing things like that:

```
ob.a = "asfasf"
console.log(ob.a); // "asfasf"
console.log(localStorage.a); "value"
```

The value don't change because ob.a equal to value, **IT NOT A REFERENCE its a VALUE**,
you get the value by doing localStorage.a!

Working version

```
var ob = { a: function(value){ return localStorage.a = value; }};
ob.a("value"); // returns "value"
console.log(localStorage.a); // "value"
```

Comment: return value not working when i am test this code ? get undefined !!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`Object.prototype.__defineGetter__()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter) and [`Object.prototype.__defineSetter__()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineSetter).

Or use the [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get) and [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/set) operators.

But remember that those are not supported in older browsers!

Answer (score 1):

Your concret problem is that you defined a primitive as attribute to the localStorage-object and not and object as an attribute to the localStorage so you do not have a reference but only a value.

A Solution could be to define the whole localStorage as attribute like this:

```
var obj = { store: localStorage };
obj.store.setItem('key','a value');
obj.store.getItem('key');
```

Comment: ohk.. Don't use Sorry !!